# mvc 5 validation and change DOM elements

Tags: validation, dom, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC 5 normal application.

In a textbot user need to write ad username (or maybe "name surname"). I use the [Remote] Annotation and a Validation function on controller is called.

Into the Validation function I make a LDAP query and if I find only 1 result I give true to validation, otherwise if nothing found or more than 1 result is found I return false.

Until here, there is no problem.

If validation is ok, I would to set the textbox value (or maybe an hidden value) with the exact AD username.

For example:
In my domain there is user marco.rossi, and is the only Marco in AD.
If I search "Marco" in AD validation is ok. But When user will submit I want pass domain\marco.rossi.

So I would set into an hidden or better change the textbox value from marco to domain\marco.rossi.

How I can set Textbox value into validation function?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For TextBox I mean <input type="text"/>

Comment: UP, is there somebody that know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a lot of search, the solution is not the BEST solution, but it's working.

I read this post: http://www.garethelms.org/2011/01/asp-net-mvc-remote-validation-what-about-success-messages/

Gareth suggest to modify the jquery.validate.js

After the "hack", for every REMOTE validation, is called a javascript function that have {Action name}_response name.

So for this:

```
 [Required]
 [Remote("CheckADUserValidation", "CONTROLLER")]
 public virtual string ad_username { get; set; }
```

I provided this function: (in the script section of the view)

```
function CheckADUserValidation_response(bIsValid, aErrors, oValidator)
{
    // I disable immediatly the submit button to wait the right username
    // so, also if validation is ok, I cannot submit until the right value is on the ad_username textbox
    $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    if (bIsValid == true) {
       // after I call an Ajax on an Action, that instead of giving me true or error messages, give me the username 

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '/CONTROLLER/ActionToHaveUsername/',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8;',
                async: true,
                data: 'ad_username=' + $('#ad_username').val(),
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response != '') {
                        // Ok there is the response
                        $('#ad_username').val(response);

                        $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                        return true;
                    } else {

                        $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        return false;
                    }

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    alert(textStatus);
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {


                }

            });


    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the Action called on the Controller:

```
 public JsonResult ActionToHaveUsername(string ad_username)
    {
        string tmpADName;
        JsonResult tmpResult = new JsonResult();

        // this function make the dirty work to take in input a name and search for unique ActiveDirectory Username, and return me in tmpADNName
        AppGlobals.functions.CheckADUserValidation(ad_username, out tmpADName);

        tmpResult.Data = tmpADName;
        tmpResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

        return tmpResult;
    }
```

The best result is encapsulating the ajax request into a timer that fires after 500ms, because I notice that sometimes the remote validation start also while writing on textbox.
So, for every character an async validation start, but when the validation return ok, the submit button is disabled and after 500ms the second request start and change the name for username. Every new character reset the timer, so only the last character fires really the second ajax.

At the end... 2 ajax is not the best scenario, but I really tried to use the JsonResult to have more data in return without lose the validation mechanism. But I don't find a way.